# O(N) execution times

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

For code in a similar form to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i+=2){
   (Code that executes in constant time)
}
```

I have heard the running time for this should be O(N). But since the loop executes n/2 times shouldn't it be O(N/2)? Can anyone explain why i increasing by two each time wouldn't also decrease the time by a factor of 2?

Comment: `O(N/2)` is equivalent to `O(N)`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time#Linear_time

Comment: What infinite is bigger natural with odds or naturals with odd+even?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we go back to Big O notation definition, it states that `f(x) ~ O(g(x))` if and only if `f(x) <= C*g(x)` where C is a constant. The constant C can be adjusted to whatever is needed and in your case the constant is 2. Constants and lower order terms are not considered when we refer to big O notation because the higher order term will always be greater than them as per the definition.

For example `O(N)` is always constant times(C) greater than `N/c1 + c2`(c1 and c2 being constants), where C can be taken as `C= c1+c2`

Another example is if we take `(N^2)+N`, we can ignore the lower order and say that complexity is `O(N^2)` because we can take constant C as 2, so `|N^2 + N| <= |N^2 + N^2| or 2|N^2|`

We can also say that `N/2 ~ O(N^2)`, however its not a tight upper bound. In complexity of algorithms we always strive towards finding the tightest bound, and since `O(N)` is a much tighter upper bound we normally use it for single variable single degree functions.

Answer (score 2):

Big O notation **does not** specify how long a function takes to run. It is only an indication of how the function's completion time changes with an increase/decrease in values. O(N) indicates a linear growth in time; likewise, O(N/2) also indicates *the exact same linear change*. When writing the time complexity of code, you can ignore any coefficients, as these do not convey any additional meaning.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with time complexity, numerical constants are ignored...the reason for this is that if you look at the long run of N and 1/2N, the constant does not radically change the result..Therefore the complexity is simply reduced to O(N)

So technically it is reduced by a factor of two, but the reduction is not great enough to take into consideration for overall run-time, therefore the run-time remains O(N)

Just to provide a picture example...The blue and red lines show that N and N/2 are basically the same in the long run...the yellowish line is Nlog(N) which by contrast does matter as you can see in the long run the time is far greater than the previous two mentioned..

[image: Just to provide a picture example...The blue and red lines show that N and N/2 are basically the same in the long run...the yellowish line is Nlog(N) which by contrast does matter as you can see in the long run the time is far greater than the previous two mentioned..]

Please Note: this answer is merely a reinforcement to why big O notation ignores constants, for a specific definition, refer to @hrv answer above

Comment: This answer is focusing on heuristics, whereas the real answer is that they're the same *by definition*.

Comment: The first part of my answer I said the latter of what you just said...The second part only reinforces what I already claimed via example

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I eagerly await your response Master Coder :)

Comment: But none of your answer touches on the *definition* of big-O ;)

Comment: Oli, correct people if you need but don't go around marking down posts as unuseful, I think Josh's post is useful as it reinforces the concepts even if it lacks the precision you want. *I'm voting back up.

Comment: @JoshF: hrv's answer is the only one I'd consider useful at the moment, as it's the only one that touches on the heart of the issue, which is that the *definition* of big-O leads to constants being irrelevant.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Point taken as far as N/2 is the same as N by definition I understand that, however, I do think my answer illustrates some of the reasoning behind said definition in a simple manner...this is how I was first taught why constants are ignored in college, to get a better grasp before moving into actual definitions as it were...I do see your point though...not sure why it merits a downvote though :P

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So vote his up, don't vote everyone else down, is all I'm sayin. The "points" aren't a big deal, but I for one try to help out everywhere I can even if I don't know as much as guys like you. It is dis-encouraging when ppl nitpick.

Comment: @JoshEngelsma: If you edit your answer to make some reference to the definition, I'd be happy to remove the downvote ;)  (IMO it's important to distinguish between the definition and heuristics(

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks, I don't want to steal hrv answer, so I just made clear with an edit that this is merely a reinforcement or illustration, not a clear cut definition and then referenced the reader to hrv's answer above, so as not to steal from his answering

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I understand your leaning towards definition over heuristics however, IMO and I think you will agree, heuristics can provide positive reinforcement to a concept...once more I await your answer, I am supposed to be studying for a Final in discrete mathematics :S

Answer (score 0):

Constants can often be factored out. The "X" is what really eats up processing time, so constants aren't that big a deal, plus Big O time like this is an approximation and really cannot be exact since the actual time depends on so many more factors. It's the same reason that when you initialize "int i=0" in your for loop, you don't give a big O time of:

O(N+1)

So, O(N) is pretty much the same as O(N/2)

Despite other users insisting that they're the same, it is a mistake to ignore constants since huge constants can really impact the run time. So yes, while O(N) might be considered the same as O(N/2), it is *pretty much* the same in that constants can have a significant impact on the overall run time (consider O(10^12N), does the huge constant matter now?)

Comment: It's not pretty much the same, it's exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you, I already knew that adding constant time was ignored just wasn't sure if multiplying N by a constant was significant.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth  So... that's a downvote? I softened it in case there's someone out there that wants to argue a difference. Does that softening make my answer completely not useful? Come on, help encourage people to contribute, not be scared to open their mouth lest someone nitpicks their answer...

Comment: But your answer is misleading; "pretty much the same" implies that they're not actually the same.

Answer (score 0):

So, let me try and explain you why it is so :

Your piece of code :

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i+=2){
   (Code that executes in constant time)
}
```

It actually depends on the underlying hardware but let us assume that each 'Assignment','Comparison','Arithmetic' ,each operation takes unit time .

So,

```
int i = 0
```

this executes only once.    `Time : 1 unit`

```
i<n
```

this executes n/2 times.    `Time : n/2 units`

```
i=i+2
```

Here, if you will see there is an Arithmetic operation as well as an Assignment operation both of which executes n/2 times,

```
Time : n/2 + n/2 = n units
```

At this point I am assuming there is nothing inside the for loop.

So total units of time required to run this loop : 1 + n/2 + n = `1 + (3n/2) units of time.`

So, for small n (which actually is in tens of thousands, in context of computation power of the underlying processor),     `1 + 3n/2 ~~ n.` as it takes a fraction of a second more/less with this small test set.

On the contrary, for large n(millions of thousands) ,`(1+(3n\2)) < n` i.e. for large test data, every coefficient definitely has its importance and could significantly affect the total execution time of the respective piece of code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : Sir, this says that it is not always true that O(N/2)~~ O(N). For computations involving a very high amount of data, O(N/2) != O(N) & people actually try to work around in such situations because bring the time complexity from O(N) of O(N/2) also could save a significant amount of processing time.

Comment: But O(N/2) == O(N) **by definition**.

Comment: I got your back Sameer, I agree that big constants do matter and your explanation helps people understand what information Big O conveys.

Comment: @JoshF: But it doesn't even slightly answer the question, i.e. the relationship between O(N) and O(N/2).